# NSRangeException error - In-App-Purchase implemantaition

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase

I've implemented an In-App-Purchase into my app. 
If I run my app and press the "purchase" button, i get the following error:

```
2014-10-22 17:48:20.733 MyApp[170:3435] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
```

Does someone got the same error and know what's to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the typical exception that emerges when handling an empty array.

Add an exception breakpoint to your project in Xcode, as shown in the picture.
It will stop the execution of the app in the line that the exception does happen

[image]